# I am getting nil and Empty when used attr_encrypted for activerecord storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, encryption, attr-encrypted

#### *I am using https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted* **for the encryptions** of my active record for ***User model***who have following attributes.

```
 
  activation_hash string  
  details string  
  email string  
  imei string  
  password string  
  registration_id string  
  secure_hash string
```

I used these attributes as

```
attr_encrypted_options.merge!(:prefix => 'android_', :suffix => '_sheild')  
attr_encrypted :activation_hash, :key => Getter::encryption_key, :encode => true  
attr_encrypted :active, :key => Getter::encryption_key, :encode => true  
attr_encrypted :code, :key => Getter::encryption_key, :encode => true  
attr_encrypted :details, :key => Getter::encryption_key, :encode => true  
attr_encryptor :email, :key => "this is awais"  
attr_encrypted :password, :key => Getter::encryption_key, :encode => true  
attr_encrypted :registration_id, :key => Getter::encryption_key, :encode => true  
attr_encrypted :secure_hash, :key => Getter::encryption_key, :encode => true
attr_encrypted :imei, :key => Getter::encryption_key, :encode => true
```

as mentioned in the attr_encrypted wiki but when i save the record empty string in stored in databases.

In Getter i have added the generic encryption key method..

```
    module Getter

      def self.encryption_key
        keys = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('aes-256-cbc').random_iv
        return keys
      end
    end
```

Do i need to add migration with encrypted attributes i added in User model..
My aim to to encrypt the activerecord data and save that fields to databases and when i retrieve i can get decrypted record back but on DB level These records are not accessible.

Can you please tell me what i do wrong?? Do i need to switch gem??

**Your suggestions are highly appreciated**

Comment: [From the doc](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted#specifying-the-encrypted-attribute-name): "By default, the encrypted attribute name is encrypted_#{attribute} (e.g. attr_encrypted :email would create an attribute named encrypted_email). So, if you're storing the encrypted attribute in the database, you need to make sure the encrypted_#{attribute} field exists in your table." Do you have such fields in your database?

Answer (score 2):

[According to the attr_encrypted documentation](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted#specifying-the-encrypted-attribute-name):

> By default, the encrypted attribute name is encrypted_#{attribute} (e.g. attr_encrypted :email would create an attribute named encrypted_email). So, if you're storing the encrypted attribute in the database, you need to make sure the encrypted_#{attribute} field exists in your table.

It seems like you did not name your fields in the expected format.

Comment: Or you can rename them?

Comment: i need to add new columns in User Table..

        ` encrypted_activation_hash  
          encrypted_details  
        encrypted_email 
        encrypted_imei  
        encrypted_password
        encrypted_registration_id `

If i have these attributes, then do i need to create user as user.encrypted_email="blah blah" or user.email= "blah blah"

Comment: The first option, I would say. Edit: nevermind. I don't have a clue, you'll have to try it out.

Comment: how can i add encrypted data to these fieldes??

do i need to save as user.encrypted_email?? I did so but empty email is stored in DB :(

Can you guide me to do this in proper manner

Comment: My guess is that: since its used like an attr_accessor helper, in your rails app's code, you should use the name given as parameter next to the attr_encrypted call (therefore just "email" for encrypted_email) but in your migration, name the actual field encrypted_email. My guess is that attr_encrypted will work it out from there.